# how to use % in min-width for page resize without squeezing content

Tags: html, css

I have css in body as

```
body {
    max-width: 100%; 
    min-width: 1880px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #eef6f9;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

this min-width helps me so that the content of a page is not minimized. I need this feature of min-width so that the content is not squeezed but I want to replace px by % or any other unit without squeezing.

I have 3 div

```
.column.side {
    min-width: 25px;
    width: 18%;
    border: 1px solid #d5e1e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #d5e1e9;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    text-align: justify;

.column.middle {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 918px;
    background-color: #eef6f9;
    border: 1px solid #d5e1e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #d5e1e9;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.column.right {
    min-width: 25px;
    width: 22%;
    border: 1px solid #d5e1e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #d5e1e9;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 70%;
}
```

This 3 div occupies overall page 100%. How can I resize a page without squeezing this division replacing min-width's px?

With min-width:1880px its working but setting 1880px seems aggressive and want to replace by other unit like %.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: what content is so big that you need 1880px width? Remove the min-width of 918px in the middle for a start. It has width of 50% specified. Images and divs can be resized in a way that "prevents squeezing" by using media queries